# Regex in JavaScript which allow maximum 10 digits, only one underscore in between the digits and prevent entering underscore after the first 5 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex that can be used to mask input field value. The conditions are following

1. Only digits and underscore are allowed
2. Only one underscore is allowed
3. Maximum 10 digits are allowed
4. Prevent entering underscore after the first 6 digits.
5. After the first 5 digits(if there no underscore added) there should display an underscore automatically
6. There should not be more than 5 digits after the underscore.

   ```
   /^\d*\_?(?:\d{1,5})?$/
   ```

The above expression can address conditions 1 and 2.

A few examples :

```
12345_67890 - Valid
123456_7890 - Not valid
12345_678901 - Not valid
1234A -Not valid
12345 - Valid
12_45_56 - Not Valid
12_45 - Valid
_12 - Valid
12_ - Valid
-678901 - Not valid
```

Comment: Does it have to a be a single regex or can it be series of test

Comment: Series of checking is okay if it can't be done using a single expression.

Comment: Did you make any attempt?

Comment: Please also include few valid/invalid examples

Comment: What is the minimum number of characters allowed?

Comment: @anubhava updated title and description to get better understanding

Comment: @Ava only number and underscore are allowed (condition 1)

Comment: I asked **minimum number** of characters

Comment: ok but why is `123456_7890` invalid?

Comment: @anubhava condition 4.

Comment: ^\d{1,5}_?\d{1,5}$

Comment: @anubhava condition 5 added, sorry.

Comment: Can it start with an underscore ?

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex:

```
^(?=(?:_?\d_?){1,10}$)\d{0,5}_?\d{0,5}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FXrbco/6)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=(?:_?\d_?){1,10}$)`: Positive lookahead to allow between 1 to 10 digits
- `\d{0,5}`: Match 0 to 5 digits
- `_?\d{0,5}`: Match an optional underscore followed by 0 to 5 digits
- `$`: End

---

> 5. After the first 5 digits(if there no underscore added) there should display an underscore automatically

Based on edited question. If you want to insert a `_` after 5 digits if it is missing then use above regex for `match` then use this next one for `replace`:

```
var repl = str.replace(/^(\d{5})(\d*)$/, '$1_$2')
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know the feedback.

Comment: 1_, _123 are valid. Please have a look.

Comment: Underscore can be anywhere except after the first 6 digits.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wp4j3tLz/
I have used the regex here, but I'm not able to clear the textbox after entering some values.

Comment: @Soojoo: I suggest to please keep Javascript form handling issue separate from regex question you posted here. For regex issue test it out on regex101 website and see if everything works for you.

Comment: Okay got it. Regarding Condition 5, I meant like if we enter 1234567890, the output should be 12345_67890.

Comment: For that just use `str = str.replace(/^(\d{5})(\d*)$/, '$1_$2')` (as shown in my answer)

Comment: Condition 6 not seems to be working, eg: _1111111111

Comment: btw here is your updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/157anxv3/ (I am not a front end developer so feel free to tweak further). At present it triggers this function on `blur` event that you can trigger by pressing `tab` after entering number.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
^(?<=\d{0,5})\d{0,5}_?\d{0,5}(?=\d{0,5})$
```

Here's how this regex works.

1. `\d{0,5}_?\d{0,5}`

   This matches the required condition. Total of 10 digits and, `_` cannot appear after 5 of them. So there we go. We check if atmost 5 digits appear, before and after `_` .
2. `(?<=\d{0,5})`

   Positive lookahead operator. Checks if there is atmost 5 digits or atleast no digits before `_`.
3. `(?=\d{0,5})`

   This is the positive lookbehind operator. This checks there is atleast none or atmost 5 digits behind `_`.
4. `^ ... $`

   This match the whole string from start to end of the line.

To know more about how lookaround operators work in regex, click [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
You can see the working regex [here](https://regexr.com/5efur).

**Note:**
Regarding the point 5 of your question, there is no single way of doing what you want. For example, if you have an input box and you're checking the input dynamically on `onChange` event and want to insert `_` after the first 5 inputted digits then depending on which framework (React/Angular/Vue) you're using, there can be different ways of achieving that.

Comment: Some warning showing there, please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @Soojoo you need not worry about them. That's a warning for lookahead operator. I can say that every browser supports them.

Comment: @Soojoo I updated how this regex works, do let me know if you did not get something.

Comment: Sure, I am checking with all possible scenarios. Thank you.

Comment: It will match a single `_` as well

Comment: Yes it will. Let's see if that is what OP wants, else I'll update it.